# Excel VBA: Writing an array to cells is very slow

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I am working with VBA in Excel to retrieve some information from the Reuters 3000 Database.  The data I retrieve comes as a bidimensional array consisting of one column holding dates and other column holding numeric values.

After I retrieve the information, a process that takes no more than 2 seconds, I want to write this data to a worksheet.  In the worksheet I have a column with dates and several other columns with numeric values, each column containing values of a same category.  I iterate over the rows of the array to get the date and numeric value and I keep those in a variable, then I search for the date on the date column of the worksheet and after I've found the date I write the value.  Here is my code:

```
Private Sub writeRetrievedData(retrievedData As Variant, dateColumnRange As String, columnOffset As Integer)

Dim element As Long: Dim startElement As Long: Dim endElement As Long
Dim instrumentDate As Variant: Dim instrumentValue As Variant
Dim c As Variant: Dim dateCellAddress As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False    
Sheets("Data").Activate
startElement = LBound(retrievedData, 1): endElement = UBound(retrievedData, 1)
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.StatusBar = "Busy writing data to worksheet"

For element = startElement To endElement
    instrumentDate = retrievedData(element, 1): instrumentValue = retrievedData(element, 2)
    Range(dateColumnRange).Select
    Set c = Selection.Find(What:=instrumentDate, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        c.offset(0, columnOffset).Value = instrumentValue            
    End If
Next element

Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

End Sub
```

My problem is that this process is very slow, even if I have only 5 rows in the array it takes about 15 seconds to complete the task.  As I want to repeat this process several times (once per each set of data I retrieve from the database), I would like to decrease the execution time as much as possible.

As you can see, I am disabling the update of the screen, which is one of the most recurrent actions to improve performance.  Does anybody have a suggestion on how I can further decrease the execution time?

PS. I know the data retrieval process does not take much because I already tested that part (displaying values on a MsgBox as soon as the data has been retrieved)

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Why is it possible for you take the entire range and have it in a 2D ARRAY? Then do the proecessing within the code and just dumb it to the range? Can you sort of show me a pic of your data sheet, I will give it try.

Comment: Do you have formulas in the sheet? You might want to turn calculations off if you do. That has caused me heartburn in the past. Maybe you can create a hashtable for your values and populate the list from a linear array? I suspect the search is what is taking forever.

Comment: Using Find() in a loop can sometimes be slow.  Loading up a Dictionary with instrument names as the keys and the range for each instrument as the value will be much faster if you have many cells to find.  And you should always avoid selecting ranges in your code: you can just do this `c.Offset(0,colOffset).Value=instrumentValue`

Comment: I would do a mix of all the above solutions. Grab all the data from the worksheet in the range you were searching, including the data you want to write to. If you do that turning off calculations wouldn't matter so much since you would only write once back to the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I did to improve the performance:

- Avoid selecting the cell when the value is going to be written.  This was a suggestion of Tim Williams.
- I set the property Application.Calculation to xlCalculationManual
- Instead of using the Find() function to search for the date, I loaded all the dates from the worksheet into an array and iterate over this array to get the row number.  This turns out to be faster than the Find() function.

  ```
  Private Function loadDateArray() As Variant

      Dim Date_Arr() As Variant

      Sheets("Data").Activate
      Date_Arr = Range(Cells(3, 106), Cells(3, 106).End(xlDown))
      loadDateArray = Date_Arr

  End Function

  Private Function getDateRow(dateArray As Variant, dateToLook As Variant)

      Dim i As Double: Dim dateRow As Double

      For i = LBound(dateArray, 1) To UBound(dateArray, 1)
          If dateArray(i, 1) = dateToLook Then
              dateRow = i
              Exit For
          End If
      Next i

      getDateRow = dateRow

  End Function
  ```

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: If your list of "compare to" items is very large, I recommend a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

By not selecting the sheet, you can add a bit more speed. Instead of

```
Sheets("Data").Activate
Date_Arr = Range(Cells(3, 106), Cells(3, 106).End(xlDown))
loadDateArray = Date_Arr
```

Try

```
With Sheets("Data")
Date_Arr = .Range(Cells(3, 106), Cells(3, 106).End(xlDown))
End With
```