# EXCEL VBA - Find dates does not work for months with 2 digits

Tags: date, excel, find, vba

I am trying to find dates in a range. This works fine for the months with 2 digits (January to September), but does not work for the remaining months. It took me some time to isolate the problem so I built a test routine.

Here is the range of data

```
12.01.2013  
12.02.2013
12.03.2013
12.04.2013
12.05.2013
12.06.2013
12.07.2013
12.08.2013
12.09.2013
12.10.2013
12.11.2013
12.12.2013
```

This is the code:

```
With wsData.Range("A1:A12")
For i= 1 To 12

    Set rReturn = .Find(What:=CDate("12." & i & ".2013"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

Next i
End With
```

For the first 9 loops I get the respective cell for rReturn. But for the last 3 loops (10 to 12) the return value is "nothing".

Comment: Take a look to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626001/excel-vba-writing-an-array-to-cells-is-very-slow/13629907#13629907) I had a similar situation where performance was very bad using the Find function to look for dates, maybe it can help you as well.

Comment: cDate uses your system settings for dates, perhaps you need to change the order of day and month, put month first

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with dates. They are strings. Also you need to format you `i` so that you can construct your exact search string.

Try this

```
Set rreturn = .Find(What:="12." & Format(i, "00") & ".2013", _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

**Tried And Tested**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim SearchString As String
    Dim i As Long

    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With wsData.Range("A1:A12")
        For i = 1 To 12
            SearchString = "12." & Format(i, "00") & ".2013"
            Set rreturn = .Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

            If Not rreturn Is Nothing Then _
            Debug.Print SearchString & " found in " & rreturn.Address
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```