# VBA slow allocation in long amount of data

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to develop a VBA macro for excel that find a value (one o more occurrences) in a quite large amount of data and copy this value to another set of data. My code is:

```
Sub FilasPallet()
Dim k As Long

  Worksheets("Datos").Range("E:F").ClearContents
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

  k = 3
  With Worksheets("Datos").Range("L:L")
  While (k < (Worksheets.Count - 1) * 28 * 25)

      Set c = .Find(Worksheets("Datos").Cells(k, 3).Value, SearchDirection:=xlNext, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
      If Not c Is Nothing Then
          firstAddress = c.Address
          oldpCount = 0
          Do
              pCount = c.Offset(0, 5).Value
              d1 = k + oldpCount
              d2 = k + oldpCount + pCount - 1
              Worksheets("Datos").Range("E" & d1 & ":E" & d2).Value = c.Offset(0, 3).Value
              Worksheets("Datos").Range("F" & d1 & ":F" & d2).Value = c.Offset(0, 4).Value
              If pCount = 25 Then
                GoTo nextiteration
              End If
              oldpCount = oldpCount + pCount
              Set c = .FindNext(c)
          Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
      Else
        Worksheets("Datos").Range("E" & k & ":E" & k + 24).Value = "No existe pallet"
      End If
nextiteration:
      Set c = Nothing
      k = k + 25

  Wend
  End With
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  MsgBox "Acabado"
End Sub
```

The main issues are this lines:

```
Worksheets("Datos").Range("E" & d1 & ":E" & d2).Value = c.Offset(0, 3).Value
Worksheets("Datos").Range("F" & d1 & ":F" & d2).Value = c.Offset(0, 4).Value
```

Because if I debug line a line the code, this lines takes too much time to finish this value copy. Whereas if I use this variation:

```
Worksheets("Datos").Range("E" & d1 & ":E" & d2) = c.Offset(0, 3).Value
Worksheets("Datos").Range("F" & d1 & ":F" & d2) = c.Offset(0, 4).Value
```

It works fine and takes the short time that I expected in the debug mode. BUT when I run the whole program, despite it runs fast, it doesn't copy the values.

Could somebody improve this code or give me another implementation idea?

Thanks!

Comment: I will use arrays, copy the range to an array at the beginning and then use a for Next loop to check all the elements of the array. FIND is very inefficient if you want to find all the matches.

Comment: Is the value being copied an exceptionally long string? Normally the lines that you have problems with should get executed pretty fast. I just copied a string of a couple of hundred characters to 2 million cells and it took around 5 seconds.

Comment: Could you explain me how replace find with the arrays that are you saying please?

Comment: No, the copied value is a short string, less than 20 characters

Comment: So how long does it take your computer to process those two lines of code? And to how many cells are you pasting, more or less?

Comment: Well, i'm doing 1064 searches (within a range of 1000 values) and for each search I paste 25 times a string. It takes about 10 minutes.

Comment: I second @CRondao's comment. Pass the range to an array and make the operations there: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx

Comment: I also second @CRondao's comment.  In addition, take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626001/excel-vba-writing-an-array-to-cells-is-very-slow/13629907#13629907 I had a similar issue.

Comment: Done men! Copying the 1000 search values into an array and looping it (with a for) for each search (1064 times) the programs takes seconds. Thanks you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem if somehow are in the same trouble. It was that using the function find intensively make the run really slow. To solve that I've copied the range into an array, as accesing memory is faster than accesing the worksheet it takes less than seconds in doing 1064 searches (within a range of 1000 values) and for each search I paste 25 times a string.

Here's the code:

```
Sub FilasPallet()
Dim k As Long
Dim pallets() As Variant
Dim palletname As String

  Worksheets("Datos").Range("E:F").ClearContents
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

  With Worksheets("Datos")
  pallets = Application.Transpose(.Range("L1:L2000").Value)
  uB = UBound(pallets)
  lB = LBound(pallets)

  amountData = .Range("C3").End(xlDown).Row
  k = 3
  While (k < amountData)
    palletname = .Cells(k, 3).Value
    oldpCount = 0
    For i = lB To uB
        If pallets(i) = palletname Then
            pCount = .Cells(i, 17).Value
            d1 = k + oldpCount
            d2 = k + oldpCount + pCount - 1
            .Range("E" & d1 & ":E" & d2) = .Cells(i, 15)
            .Range("F" & d1 & ":F" & d2) = .Cells(i, 16)
            oldpCount = oldpCount + pCount
            If oldpCount = 25 Then
                GoTo break
            End If
        End If
    Next i
break:
    If oldpCount <> 25 Then
        .Range("E" & k & ":E" & k + 24).Value = "No existe pallet"
    End If
    k = k + 25
   Wend
  End With

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  MsgBox "Completado! Voy a recalcular todas las formulas de la tabla. Puede tardar un poco."
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  MsgBox "FIN"
End Sub
```