# Excel VBA: populating cells with array values is very slow

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am trying to do some data formatting for QuickBooks exports and one step is very slow. I have a sheet called "Output" which has every entry laid out in the desired format, but I only want the fully populated ones to be used on another sheet called "Map".

Everything up to this point is done with formulas and that part works fine. I wrote a small script to loop over the total entries and pull the relevant information from "Output" into five different arrays. It then loops back over those arrays and populates the cells in the appropriate columns in "Map".

My script populates the arrays quickly, but populating the cells takes a very long time. I use a for loop to iterate over the arrays and each iteration takes about three seconds which is a very long time when you are dealing with thousands of entries.

```
Sub Prettify()

    Dim numbers()
    Dim catagories()
    Dim classes()
    Dim subclasses()
    Dim values()

    Dim count As Integer

    count = 2

    ' The upper bounds of the loop is a calculation of the number of entries we will access

    For i = 2 To (Sheets("Data").Cells(7, 8).Value * Sheets("Data").Cells(4, 3).Value + 2)


        If (Sheets("Output").Cells(i, 1).Value = "") Then

            ' Do Nothing

        Else

            ReDim Preserve numbers(count)
            ReDim Preserve catagories(count)
            ReDim Preserve classes(count)
            ReDim Preserve subclasses(count)
            ReDim Preserve values(count)

            count = count + 1

            numbers(count - 2) = Val((Sheets("Output").Cells(i, 1).Value))
            catagories(count - 2) = Sheets("Output").Cells(i, 2).Value

            If (Sheets("Output").Cells(i, 3).Value = 0) Then

                classes(count - 2) = Sheets("Output").Cells(i, 4).Value
                subclasses(count - 2) = ""

            Else

                classes(count - 2) = Sheets("Output").Cells(i, 3).Value
                subclasses(count - 2) = Sheets("Output").Cells(i, 4).Value

            End If

            values(count - 2) = Sheets("Output").Cells(i, 5).Value

        End If

    Next

    MsgBox (numbers(0))
    MsgBox (catagories(0))

    Sheets("Map").Activate

    '  This next part is slow

    For j = 2 To count

        Sheets("Map").Cells(j, 1).Value = numbers(j - 2)
        Sheets("Map").Cells(j, 2).Value = catagories(j - 2)
        Sheets("Map").Cells(j, 3).Value = classes(j - 2)
        Sheets("Map").Cells(j, 4).Value = subclasses(j - 2)
        Sheets("Map").Cells(j, 5).Value = values(j - 2)

    Next

End Sub
```

There was a similar issue to mine in a post about three years ago, but the fixes they used were not applicable to my example. I tested the code at various points using message boxes and each of the five assignment steps in the last for loop are equally slow. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you link to the question you mentioned? How many values are we talking about?

Comment: What happens when you do `Sheets("Map").Range("A2:A"& count).Value = numbers` instead of a loop?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626001/excel-vba-writing-an-array-to-cells-is-very-slow

Comment: Nothing gets populated when I do that unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the edit DAXaholic!

Comment: You have to read the worksheet to Array , and write back without Loop.
The Looping is then reserved in between for working with data (on arrays, not on sheet).
Or else it won't be "fast". Also try to assign sheets to variables when referincing, or use the `With` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this issue, the problem is that your code is accessing each cell one after the other. Turning the screen off and events will help but it will still be slow and crippling with larger arrays.

The solution is to dump the everything into the cells in one go. To achieve this you will need to use Multidimensional arrays. That sounds really complex but its not once you get your head round it.

It also looks as though you are getting your data out of the workbook the same way.

Here is some code that should sort it, its going to look really simple but it really works.

```
Dim v_Data() as variant
Dim range_to_Load as range
Dim y as long, x as long
'set a range or better still use a list object
set range_to_Load = thisworkbook.sheets("Data").Range("A1:F100")
'Load the range into a variant array.
with range_to_Load
    redim v_data(1 to .rows.count, 1 to .columns.count)
    v_data = .value
end with
' v_data now holds all in the range but as a multidimentional array
' to access it its going to be like a grid so 
v_data(row in the range, column in the range)
'Loop through the array, I'm going to covert everything to a string then
'dump it in the Map sheet you have
' you should avoid x,y as variables however this is a good use as they are coordinate values.
'lbound and ubound will loop y though everything by row as it is the first dimension in the array. 
For y = lbound(v_data) to ubound(v_data) 
    ' next we are going to do the same but for the second dimention
    For x = lbound(v_data,2) to ubound(v_data,2)
         vdata(y,x) = cstr(v_data(y,x))
    Next x
Next y
'We have done something with the array and now want to put it somewhere, we could just drop it where we got it from to do this we  would say
range_to_Load.value = v_data
' to put it else where
thisworkbook.sheets("Map").range("A1").resize(ubound(v_data), ubound(v_data,2)).value = v_data
```

That should sort your problem, you can do sooooo much with this. Read up on Multi dimensional arrays, Chip Pearson as per usual has lots to say and will help.

You can process huge sets in second rather than minutes as in an array all is done in memory the only access to the workbook comes when you take the data and drop it back in, thus really minimizing the time needed to run your code.

Comment: Awesome! This basically solved my problem. I had to make a few modifications to ignore certain entries which we want to be ignored, but using the multidimensional array and assigning the values all at once did the trick. I will post my final code as well. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try using this at the start of your code

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
```

And at the end, add

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True
```

Now, you will have an issue if your code breaks, because I have turned your calculation to manual. So you should add an error handler. If this is a little too complicated, remove all bar the screen updating one

So at the top, also add

```
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
```

And at the end add:

```
Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True

End Sub
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Kamilla Whatling suggested using multidimensional arrays, Range objects, and a different kind of cell population to speed up the process. They worked and below is the final project code which works quickly and removes unwanted entries at the same time.

```
Sub Prettify()

Dim values() As Variant
Dim usableRange As Range
Dim rangeSelection As String
Dim entryNumber As Long
Dim count As Long

count = 0

entryNumber = Sheets("Data").Cells(4, 3).Value * Sheets("Data").Cells(7, 8).Value

rangeSelection = "A2:E" & (entryNumber + 1)

Set usableRange = Sheets("Output").Range(rangeSelection)

For i = 1 To entryNumber

    If Sheets("Output").Cells(i, 1) = "" Then

    Else

        count = count + 1

    End If

Next

ReDim values(count, 5)
count = 0

For i = 1 To entryNumber

    If usableRange.Cells(i, 1) = "" Then

    Else

        values(count, 0) = usableRange.Cells(i, 1).Value
        values(count, 1) = usableRange.Cells(i, 2).Value

        If usableRange.Cells(i, 3).Value = 0 Then

            values(count, 2) = usableRange.Cells(i, 4).Value
            values(count, 3) = ""

        Else

            values(count, 2) = usableRange.Cells(i, 3).Value
            values(count, 3) = usableRange.Cells(i, 4).Value

        End If

        values(count, 4) = usableRange.Cells(i, 5).Value

        count = count + 1

    End If

Next

Sheets("Map").Range("A2").Resize(UBound(values), 5).Value = values

End Sub
```

Thanks for all your helps folks!